# Get all build orders from a given model.

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have problem. I need for my work all possible build orders for some components. As a simple example you can imagine a simple Lego pyramid:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Lcr.jpg

I tried some kind of DFS but it didn't work out. There are missing some possbilities at the end.

Can anyone help me with that? Language should be C++ but I just need a hint not a complete algorithm.

Some informations: The models are available as XML files. There you can find all neighbourhood relationships in all 3 directions (x, y, z). All pieces have an unique name/id. The beginning is not defined. There is no restriction in the build order. So you don't have to finish one level of the pyramid to start another one. I know there are a lot of possible build orders. Even the 3x3-base on its own has a lot of possibilities (nine factorial). But it doesn't matter at the moment.

Please I need help.

Greetings,
Eric

Comment: I do not really understand your problem. If there is no restriction on build order at all, then there are N! possible build orders for N pieces.

Comment: what is a DFS? I tried to find out but other than "Distributed File System" and a company selling furniture I didnt find anything related.

Comment: @tobi303 [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: You seem to be looking for all 14! permutations. Have you tried smaller permutation problems?

Comment: Sorry. I should have said, that only feasible build orders should be "calculated". So imagine you have a ground plate and want to have any possible build order for this pyramid.

Answer (score 1):

First, treat each layer (or "course") as an independent problem. Consider the nine bricks on the bottom; ignoring all others, there are 9! possible orders, so generate those, call them **P**. Likewise the 4! possible orders for the middle bricks are **Q**. We can ignore the single brick at the top for now.

Iterate over **P** and **Q**. Given an ordering of the bottom bricks, **p**, and of the middle bricks, **q**, it may be that the first move of **q** (i.e. laying the first mid-level brick) is possible before the bottom is complete, so we can intersperse that move with the moves of **p**; for each permitted time of the first of **q**, iterate over the permitted times of the second of **q**, and for each of them iterate over the permitted times of the third, and so on.

Notice that the top brick must always be placed last. Good thing, too.

Is that enough to go on?

Answer (score 0):

If there  aren't *any* limits to the order of the placement, then there are exactly `n!` different [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the orders that the blocks can be placed. In that case, a simple solution is to put all the blocks (or rather, their id's) into a vector and generate all the permutations with [std::next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/).